# C++ boost 1.72 reconnect on tcp::socket throwing an exception with WSAEADDRINUSE on linux, but works on Windows

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, boost

Hi my code works properly on windows but on linux the reconnect feature doesn't work,it throws an exception with `WSAEADDRINUSE` value.

```
pClientSocket = new tcp::socket(*pIO_context, tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::make_address(127.0.0.1, 50001));
```

First time it works on both Windows and Linux, but when i close the socket and try to connect again, i am getting an exception as described above only on linux OS.

Here is the close socket code.

```
boost::system::error_code ec;
pClientSocket->shutdown( boost::asio::socket_base::shutdown_type::shutdown_receive, ec);
pClientSocket->close(eCode);

delete pClientSocket;

pClientSocket= nullptr;
```

Comment: I don't know that boost interface but socket() has a flag SO_REUSEADDR if there's an equivalent one in boost you can try?

Comment: Otherwise you might just have to give the system a short while to close any open connections it had on that socket before you can reuse the port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the reuse option:

```
boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address option(true);
socket.set_option(option);
```

**Update:**

This usually happens we you try to bind a server socket to an address that is already in use or it has been used recently (and the socket is still waiting to be cleaned up by the OS).

With client sockets this is less common, you will have to force a port -by calling bind()- in the socket in order for this to happen.

Now the code:

```
pClientSocket = new tcp::socket(*pIO_context, tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::make_address(127.0.0.1, 50001)); 
boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address option(true); 
socket.set_option(option);
```

Calls [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/basic_stream_socket/overload3.html) constructor overload. This constructor creates the socket and tries to bind it to the specified address. It fails because you didn't had the chance to specify the reuse option.

On the other hand, this code:

```
pClientSocket = new tcp::socket(*pIO_context); 
pClientSocket->open(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4()); 
pClientSocket->set_option(socket_base::reuse_address(true));

boost::system::error_code ec; 
pClientSocket->bind(tcp::endpoint(make_address(127.0.0.1, 50001), ec); 
if (ec) { }
```

Calls [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/basic_stream_socket/overload1.html) constructor overload, which just creates the socket but doesn't open no connect it. This allows to specify any socket option before bind/connect, etc.

Comment: i was using the code like this which was not working.
pClientSocket = new tcp::socket(*pIO_context, tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::make_address(127.0.0.1, 50001));
boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address option(true);
socket.set_option(option);

the new code which works properly.
pClientSocket = new tcp::socket(*pIO_context);
pClientSocket->open(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4());
pClientSocket->set_option(socket_base::reuse_address(true));
boost::system::error_code ec;
pClientSocket->bind(tcp::endpoint(make_address(127.0.0.1, 50001), ec);
if (ec)
{
}

Comment: yes! you are right. I should have noted that in my answer, which I just did btw :-)